# Writing to Google Spreadsheet API Extremely Slow

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to write data from here(http://acleddata.com/api/acled/read) to Google Sheets via its API.I'm using the gspread package to help.

Here is the code:

```
r = requests.get("http://acleddata.com/api/acled/read")
data = r.json()
data = data['data']
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('credentials.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
for row in data:
    sheet.append_row(row.values())
```

The data is a list of dictionaries, each dictionary representing a row in a spreadsheet. This is writing to my Google Sheet but it is unusably slow. It took easily 40 minutes to write a hundred rows, and then I interrupted the script.

Is there anything I can do to speed up this process?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, you're using the older [V3 Google Data API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/).  For better performance, switch to the [V4 API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/).  A migration guide is available [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration).

Comment: thanks for the response. Ill check this out. In the meantime, i figured out what is probably the main reason--that using this append_row method makes api calls each time it does it. Ill post the fix I found below

Answer (score 1):

Here is the faster solution:

```
cell_list = sheet.range('A2:'+numberToLetters(num_columns)+str(num_lines+1))
for cell in cell_list:
    val = df.iloc[cell.row-2, cell.col-1]
    if type(val) is str:
        val = val.decode('utf-8')
    elif isinstance(val,(int, long, float, complex)):
        val= int(round(val))
    cell.value = val
sheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

This is derived from here https://www.dataiku.com/learn/guide/code/python/export-a-dataset-to-google-spreadsheets.html

I believe the change here is that this solution creates a cell_list object, which only requires one API call.

Answer (score 1):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/190), Google Spreadsheets API can be pretty slow depending on many factors including your connection speed to Google servers, usage of proxy, etc. Avoid having `gspread.login` inside a loop because this method is slow.

> *...[`get_all_records`](http://burnash.github.io/gspread/#gspread.Worksheet.get_all_records) came to my rescue, much faster than range for entire sheet.*

I have also read in this [forum](http://www.indjango.com/access-google-sheets-in-python-using-gspread/) that it depends on the size of the worksheet, so as the rows increase in the worksheet, the program run even more slower.